# Redirection to a specific web page based on URL parameter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-rewriting

I have a simple .htm web page kept in different folders for handling different languages.

default.htm inside en folder (**en\default.htm**  and **de\default.htm** and so on)

I need to redirect to a specific web page based on the URL parameter i.e. if the user had

specified `http://localhost/website/default.htm?lang=de`, i need to redirect him to the

**de\default.htm** file. i.e. a german web page.

had it been the ASPX pages i would have done away with the job easily with ResourceManager

and an appropriate .resx file using the **Request.QueryString** option provided by .NET

BCL. However since i'm using plain HTML page i do not have an  expertise to write a client

side script like javascript to query for the URL parameters and redirect the user to the

required page.

**Question :**

Can anyone guide me how do i achieve the same using any form of client scripting to

achieve the redirection ?? And where do i invoke the script function ?

i.e query the parameter for each post event.??

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript to get a list of params pretty easily with the following line.

`var paramArray = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&")`

This will build an array of the parameters of the query string. From there you just need to add logic to find the param you specified in your question and take the appropriate redirect using

`window.location.href = 'some URL'; //causes the browser to refresh with the new URL`

**Example:**

```
function getQueryStringArray(){
    var assoc=[]; 
    var items = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&'); 
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) { 
       var a = items[j].split('='); assoc[a[0]] = a[1]; 
    }
    return assoc;
}

//point at which you want to determine redirection
var qs = getQueryStringArray();
var url = '';
if (qs.lang !== 'undefined' && qs.lang) {
   switch (qs.lang) {
      case 'en':
         url = 'blah';
         break;
      case 'de': 
         url = 'meh';
         break;
   }
   window.location.href = url; //reroute
 }
```

Comment: Getting a redirection error in Mozilla ... It says **Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (d) isn't associated with any program.**

Comment: This means it's not a code issue mate. It's a URL formatting issue. Check the formatting of your URLs. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/The%20protocol%20is%20not%20associated%20with%20any%20program

Answer (score 2):

See this on how to parse query string parameters using jQuery [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Then you can redirect to another page with window.location

Something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var p = getParameterByName("lang");
   var rootUrl = "yourRootUrl";
    var url = rootUrl + p + '/default.htm';
   window.location = url;
});
</script>
```

No jQuery

```
<script>
     (function(){
          var p = getParameterByName("lang");
          var rootUrl = "yourRootUrl/";
          var url = rootUrl + p + '/default.htm';
          window.location = url;
     }());
</script>
```

Comment: No it's not, but it wasn't specified that jQuery is not be used either. It's just another option. Also, I am leveraging an existing solution from S.O and not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It's not about reinventing the wheel, it's about two things: 1) OP didnt' ask how to do it in using jQuery. 2) Your answer requires him to incorporate an entirely new library just to support this language rerouting bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it for you. Just wrap it in `<script></script>` tags.

```
// Locate "lang=...." in the url using regex;
var a = /[\?&]lang=([^\/&#\?]+)/i.exec(window.location.pathname);
// check if the regex matched
if (a) {
    // If so, redirect the user
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/website/" + a[1] + "/index.htm";
}
```

This will save you from having to loop through the url, but it does require a basic understanding of how regexp works.