# How can I use an URL parameter to redirect to a page?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to create a simeple page on my website that redirects users to another page based on url parameters in javascript.
Basically I want to have something like this url `https://example.com/go?redirect=google.com` that when visited redirects users to google or any url entered in after `?redirect=`.

Is this possible in JavaScript, and if so how would I go about writing code to make this function?

Comment: Maybe this will solve it if someone has the same problem, haven't tried it yet but just found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823784/redirection-to-a-specific-web-page-based-on-url-parameter-using-javascript

Comment: You could read [query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var navigate = url.searchParams.get("redirect");
    window.location.href=navigate;
```

Comment: It did work partially. The script knows the parameter and everything, however it redirects to example.com/google.com instead of just google.com.